# Are these usages of pronominal verbs correct to translate "She opened up to me"?

Tags: verbo-pronominal

Are the following examples proper ways to say, "She opened up to me":

> Ella se abrió a mí.
>
> A mí ella me abrió
>
> Ella se me abrió.
>
> A mí ella se me abrió.

I'm using examples of the idiomatic pronominal verb *abrirse*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the examples with *se*, the meaning of the verb would be (as intended) something like "to open up", in the figurative sense (letting other person know about one's feelings or intentions). This is meaning #30 of the entry for *[abrir](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=0BIq0lQ)* in the *Diccionario de la Lengua Española*:

> **30.** prnl. Dicho de una persona: Declararse, descubrirse, confiarse a otra. *Se abrió conmigo.*

Note how the definition employs the verb *confiarse (a alguien)*; that's another pronominal verb.

Using the preposition *a* for the recipient of the action is not usual in this meaning of *abrir* (as you see, the example in the DLE employs *con*), but it's OK.

Your examples with *se* are pronominal. *Se* acts like a direct object and refers back to the subject, which is third person *ella*. If the subject were first or second person, singular or plural, the pronoun would have to change (it would be *me, te, nos,* or *os*).

The recipient of the action (me) appears as the indirect object, in two ways: as the clitic (unstressed) pronoun *me*, and as the full (stressed) pronoun *mí* preceded by the preposition *a*.

The three pronominal examples mean the same: "She opened up to me." Only the emphasis is different. There are some complicated rules governing how to use the two types of pronouns and the word order, which I won't cover here.

The sentence without *se* has *abrir* in its basic sense. As it is, it would be usually understood with an implicit direct object (the thing being opened, a door?), and the indirect object would be the beneficiary of the action. In your example the unusual word order shows [topicalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization):

> *A mí ella me abrió.* = "For me she opened (the door)."

If you don't need emphasis you would just say:

> *Ella me abrió.* = "She opened (the door) for me."

Note that in English you open the door **for** someone (a [benefactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benefactive_case) construction), while in Spanish you "open someone the door" (*abrir* works as a [ditransitive verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb)).

Alternatively, the verb might work as a transitive form of its (usually intransitive) pronominal version:

> *Ella me abrió.* = "She opened me up." or "She got me to open up."

Comment: Though somewhat unusual, "A mí ella me abrió" might also be used to mean that, the speaker being an introverted or reserved person, she acted in such a way that he started to be sociable and outgoing.

Comment: Just edited to add note from @Gustavson's comment.